# Implicit return value of Array#map in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Given the following code:

```
class MagicList
  def items=(array)
    @items = array.map{|x| x*2}
  end

  def items
    @items
  end
end

list = MagicList.new
returns = list.items=([1, 2, 3])

puts returns.inspect    # => [1, 2, 3]
puts list.items.inspect # => [2, 4, 6]
```

I expected the value of `returns` to be `[2, 4, 6]`, because `@items` as well as `array.map{|x| x*2}` both return this value. Why is it `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Because `Array#map` doesn't change the original variable; `Array#map!` changes the original variable.

Comment: But I do not return the default variable. Even when I add `return @items` to `def items=` it still returns the original array.

Comment: @iblue Setters always return the right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: @RobertK It's still the last expression in the method and thus would be returned if the method weren't a setter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Ruby assignments always return the item they were passed, regardless of what the `setter=` method returns.

See also [Is it possible to have class.property = x return something other than x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708618/is-it-possible-to-have-class-property-x-return-something-other-than-x)

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Where is this documented?

Comment: @Gareth to be specific, the `items=` method _does_ return `[2,4,6]`, it's the assignment that is working differently when a `=` is involved.

Comment: @Stefan I'm not sure where you get that impression from. `returns = (list.items = [1, 2, 3])` would show that the return value of the setter is the same as the argument that's passed in. If `[2, 4, 6]` was being returned then how could the `returns` variable be set to anything else?

Comment: @Gareth: `list.send(:items=, [1, 2, 3])` returns `[2, 4, 6]`

Comment: @Gareth Ruby sets the `variable` to the right-most value because of the chained assignment. Try `returns = list.send(:items=,[1,2,3])`

Comment: Race condition for the win! :)