# Return save outcome inside begin/ensure block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a setter method for an attr_accessor in rails

```
 # setter method of the shopify_p accessor
 def shopify_v=(s)
   begin
     self.product.shop.connect_to_store
     @shopify_v = s if s.save
   ensure
     ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
   end
 end
```

I'd like it to return true if save is successful or false if the save action doesn't work.

Instead it always outputs the s object (or @shopify_v, I don't know).

How can I make it return true or false depending on the save action?

Thanks,
Augusto

**UPDATE #1**

Here is the getter method of the same attr_accessor.
Basically it downloads the object from the server only in case it has never done it before.

```
      # getter method of the shopify_v accessor
      def shopify_v
       if @shopify_v.nil?
         begin
           self.product.shop.connect_to_store
           @shopify_v = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(self.shopify_id)
         ensure
           ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
         end
         puts "remote"
         return @shopify_v
       else
         puts "local"
         return @shopify_v
       end
      end
```

Comment: It's better, if you can do it, to raise an exception and catch it in the caller.  A good rule of thumb is that methods should either have side effects _or_ return something, but not both.

Comment: Agreed, I find it bad form to let an assignment return a `true` or `false` to indicate whether or not it succeeded. I would expect an assignment to _always_ succeed. Otherwise use a method that would clarify this changed semantic.

Comment: @WayneConrad, can you explain me better your though?
Here I'm using this method to save an object to a remote server.  I would like the method to return true/false, so that I can use it in my application and when I try to save remotely, if nothing bad happens (with connection, server, etc...) I can create a local copy of the object. Instead if the setter method return false I want not to save the object locally.

Comment: Sure.  I've added an answer.  Sorry I couldn't get to it until the weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use exceptions, since being unable to save is an exceptional condition.  Also, whenever practical, a method should *either* have a side-effect, or return a value.

For example:

```
class ShopifyError < StandardError ; end

def shopify_v=(s)
   begin
     self.product.shop.connect_to_store
     raise ShopifyError unless s.save
     @shopify_v = s
   ensure
     ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
   end
 end
```

and in the caller:

```
begin
    ...
    model.v = s
    ...
rescue ShopifyError
    # set flash[:notify], or whatever error handling is appropriate
end
```

---

Also, there are cleaner ways to structure the getter.  Consider doing something like this:

```
  # getter method of the shopify_v accessor
  def shopify_v
    @shopify_v ||= fetch_v
  end

  private

  def fetch_v
     begin
       self.product.shop.connect_to_store
       ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(self.shopify_id)
     ensure
       ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def shopify_v=(s)
  begin
    self.product.shop.connect_to_store
    @shopify_v = s if s.save
  ensure
    ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
  end
  @shopify_v.present? # will return true or false
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but still it doesn't work. It still strangely outputs a Shopify object...

Comment: Odd, someone edited my answer to one that wouldn't work. Rolled-back.

Comment: @Unixmonkey: I did edit the answer because begin/end is not needed in this case, but yes, I did forget to add the return statement

Comment: this still has a problem, this `@shopify_v` may be an old value.

Comment: @Unixmonkey tried your original solution too but still it outputs the object instead of true/false.

Comment: @Augusto Does your Rails environment need reloading? Is this method name being monkeypatched, or there is already a db column named shopify_v?

Comment: @Unixmonkey I reloaded the Rails environment before every test.  I updated my question with the setter method of the same attr_accessor.  (I don't have a db column named shopify_v).

Answer (score 1):

A setter *always* returns the value being set, no matter what you try to return. So you should use another method name, for example:

```
def set_shopify_v(s)
  self.product.shop.connect_to_store
  status = s.save
  @shopify_v = s if status
  status
rescue => exc
  # Rails.logger.error(...) 
  false
ensure
  ShopifyAPI::Base.site = nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks tokland, tried your solution but still it outputs the object, instead of true or false.  I really cannot figure out why :(

Comment: oh, it's a setter! of course it returns always the object, it's how they work, it's a special method type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708618/is-it-possible-to-have-class-property-x-return-something-other-than-x

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction, tokland!  What do you mean by "can you use another name?"

Comment: I mean anything but a "method=", set_method, whatever.

Comment: Is there any downside in not using a setter method?  Will I be still able to use the getter?