# setter method return self not work, it's a bug?

Tags: ruby

I want to iterate an array of strings, and assign each of them to a fresh instance of class User, and I expect that I will got an array of User objects:

```
class User
  def name=(name)
    @name = name
    self
  end
end

original_array = ["aaa", "bbb", "bbb"]
result = original_array.collect { |str| User.new.name = str }
```

but the result is an array of strings!

```
puts result.inspect            # => ["aaa", "bbb", "bbb"]
puts result === original_array # => true
```

I have no idea of where I went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong here is that `User.new.name = str` returns `str`, so the value of `str` gets collected.

Why does it return `str`? Because, opposed to any other Ruby method, **every Ruby setter method returns the passed value, regardless the returned value in the method**. For more infos about this behaviour you can check [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708618/is-it-possible-to-have-class-property-x-return-something-other-than-x).

Below a IRB-ready Proof of Concept:

```
def name=(name)
  @name = 'another value'
end

returned_value = (self.name = 'a value')

returned_value #=> 'a value'
@name          #=> 'another value'
```

---

What you want can be done in this ways:

- This syntax is valid for any Ruby object, as it uses [`Object#tap`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

  ```
  User.new.tap { |v| v.name = str }
  ```
- If `User` is an `ActiveRecord` model, as I guess, you can use one of these slightly shorter syntaxes:

  ```
  User.new name: str
  User.new { |v| v.name = str }
  ```

Comment: I have override the setter method, and returned `self` back. But it seems like the return value is the `str`.

Comment: @hbin: The return value from a setter is ignored by Ruby. You get the return value from *assignment* `=` instead. If you don't want that, don't use assignment syntax.

Comment: @mdesantis thanks a lot! And the `tap` method can be an alternative `original_array.collect { |str| User.new.tap { |u| u.name=str } }`

Comment: @hbin right! I wanted to write an example using `tap` too, but I gussed `User` to be an `ActiveRecord` model, so I didn't write it... but reading better your question you have never cited ActiveRecord nor Rails... I'll updated the answer