# Why does one method return an array while the other doesn't?

Tags: ruby, rspec

My first code looks like this:

```
def title(name)
  string = []
  name.split.each do |word|
    string << word.capitalize
  end
  string.join(' ')
end

print title('bob doe')
```

This returns:

```
Bob Doe
```

My second code looks like this:

```
class Book
  def title
    @title
  end

  def title=(book_name)
    @title = []
    book_name.split.each do |word|
      @title << word.capitalize
    end
    @title.join(' ')
  end
end
```

The RSpec exercise I'm working on is asking me to capitalize whatever title it gives me. In this case, let's say they want

```
expect(@book.title).to eq("Inferno")
```

I guess my question is, how come the second code returns ["Inferno"] when the first code returned the results without the array?

I'm still quite new to programming, so thank you for any explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title=` does *return* the joined string, just like `title` does. But you're not using the return value of `title=`, you're using the value assigned to `@title`. `@title.join('')` *returns* the joined string, but it doesn't assign the joined string to `@title`. When `title=` exits, `@title` is still the array you constructed with the `each`.

Fix it like this:

```
class Book
  def title
    @title
  end

  def title=(book_name)
    @title = []
    book_name.split.each do |word|
      @title << word.capitalize
    end
    @title = @title.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Note that [the return value of an assignment method normally doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708618/is-it-possible-to-have-class-property-x-return-something-other-than-x), although it makes the most sense to return the assigned value, as the fixed method does.

Also note that experienced Rubyists would normally write those methods more succinctly:

```
class Book
  attr_reader :title

  def title=(book_name)
    @title = book_name.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  end
end
```

Presumably the tutorial you're following will eventually get around to the features of Ruby used in those versions of those methods.